# Is there any way to allow for scrolling in for cells in a tableviewcontroller using storyboards in Xcode with Objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a standard tableview/coredata set up that fills (my own class defined) cells with users data as they enter it in. The only problem is, once there are too many cells to fit on the screen, the lower ones get cut off and are only visible once the top ones get deleted. Is there anyway to add the scroll feature now or is it too late (i have seen a few recommendations which involve either using xibs or using a view controller with a scrollbar feature).

Comment: minimal working example please

Answer (score 0):

I feel really stupid right now, but i do have the answer if anyone else comes across the same "problem". It turns out that scrolling is automatically enabled and while you cannot scroll down just from swiping down on the touchpad (macbook), actually clicking while scrolling down using the touchpad allows for scrolling (and will show scroll bar on the side, which is not visible unless it is in use)